# Chrome for android issue regarding html5 canvas and text / filltext

Tags: android, google-chrome, canvas, cross-browser, html5-canvas

I am currently creating a game in HTML5 using Canvas. Right now, it works pretty well with all the internet browsers except Google Chrome for Android which refuses to display my "filltext" commands...

I noticed that the game worked when I disabled the 2D acceleration of Chrome Android through chrome://flags/... but i obviously cannot ask users to disable their 2D acceleration feature of Chrome prior to playing. Does anybody have a solution to display my filltext under google chrome for android?

You will find below the code: basically, i can see the text in all the browsers except chrome for android... it draws the background and not the text.

> //Get the canvas
>     var canvas2 = document.getElementById("layer2");
>     var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
>
> //Rendering function (draw background and draw image)
>     var render = function () {
>     ctx2.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
>     ctx2.fillText("Lolo", 400, 400);
>     }
>
> // main loop
>     var main = function () {
>     var now = Date.now();
>     var delta = now - then;
>     update(delta / 1000);
>     render();
>     then = now;
>     };
>     var then = Date.now();
>     setInterval(main, 1);

Thank you!

Laurent

Comment: Bug fixed in the chrome beta version (2D acceleration is not triggered anymore when canvas size is big) but still, if you have a solution...

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug with the software renderer, you will need to make your canvas at least 256 pixels in size to force it in to the GPU path.  Paul Lewis face a similar problem and [blogged about it](http://www.aerotwist.com/blog/making-a-60fps-mobile-app/)

If you can provide a reduced demo, I will file the Bug against Chrome (or you can do it at http://m.crbug.com/new)